# Angular.js Express.js Passport logout redirection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

Sample Code (using passport-local on angular-fullstack):

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    console.log('testing123');
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Whenever this code executes, the url displays /logout for a moment before reverting back to the main page. The logout function seems to be running accordingly, and I have attempted to setup a route client side using angular to hold a blank html template to confirm. The bug is in the redirection, coming from a link on the navbar. Also, no log appears in the console on the browser (not that it should) or terminal.

Attempted Solutions:

1.) Adding in the route client side to create test template to ensure app.get(url/logout) has been called and logout() has been implemented.

2.) Changing the redirect route to another template. (Same effect)

3.) Inspecting both route reversions that account for non-registered routes for the client and the express server. This was done through the inclusion on both sides of '/logout' routes being instantiated and tested.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Resolution:** 
$http get request, upon success, redirected to login using $location.path()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the route is hit by an xhr request the app won't go anywhere because you are not redirecting the browser just the ajax call, you have to implement listen for the logout call response on your angular app and clear your headers and redirect the browser

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, I scrap the logout call server side, listen for the response client side to the logout xhr request, and clear my headers from the browser? Couldn't I just avoid the xhr all together then and just clear the header from the client with an onclick event?

Comment: you could if you don't have to do any server side work,  like updating logout times or disabling tokens, or clearing cookies, thats all based on  your architecture

Comment: if I were trying to add middleware to

`app.get('/', middleware, function(req, res) {
    res.send(200);
}`

Where the middleware checks for a session's user, would the same principle apply? Would I have to handle the redirection to the login page from the client?

Comment: to the client is irrelevant if your auth logic relies on the handler or in a middleware function.  so yes everything would remain the same